# Convert ISO 639-1 to ISO 639-2

Tags: python, iso-639

I need to take an [ISO 639-1 code](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Language_localisation&oldid=685931772#Language_tags_and_codes) such as `en-GB` and convert it into an [ISO 639-2 code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639-2) such as `eng`.

I have looked at the following libraries, but did not find a documented means to perform that transformation in any of them:

- [BabelFish](https://pythonhosted.org/babelfish/)
- [langcodes](https://github.com/LuminosoInsight/langcodes)
- [pycountry](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycountry)

Have I missed something? That is - is this possible with any of these libraries?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `pycountry` for what you want. Do note that if you want the reverse scenario (ISO 639-2 to ISO 639-1) it may not always work because while there should always be a mapping from an ISO 639-1 language code to ISO 639-2, the reverse is not guaranteed.

```
import pycountry

code = 'en-GB'

# ISO 639-1 codes are always 2-letter codes, so you have to take
# the first two characters of the code

# This is a safer way to extract the country code from something
# like en-GB (thanks ivan_pozdeev)
lang_code = code[:code.index('-')] if '-' in code else code

lang = pycountry.languages.get(iso639_1_code=lang_code)
print("ISO 639-1 code: " + lang.iso639_1_code)
print("ISO 639-2 code: " + lang.iso639_2T_code)
print("ISO 639-3 code: " + lang.iso639_3_code)
```

The above should print out:

```
ISO 639-1 code: en
ISO 639-2 code: eng
ISO 639-3 code: eng
```

Comment: Thanks, this was v.helpful. The [Wikipedia article I linked](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Language_localisation&oldid=685931772#Language_tags_and_codes) had confused me: even though its wording talks of the ISO 639-1 "alpha-2 code" and "two-letter codes", the table shows the string `en-GB` as an example of an "ISO 639-1 code", which left me thinking that the whole string was a valid ISO 639-1 code, not just the first two letters of the string. That in turn is why I thought the libraries I had listed might not be able to perform the transformation I needed. Now off to read BCP 47!

Comment: `code[:code.index('-')]` appears to be more reliable to extract the first part (so the code will choke if it's not 2-letter). It won't work if there's only one part already. Something like `code[:code.index('-')] if '-' in code else code` will work in all cases.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev - Thanks for that, I've updated my code to include that line.

Comment: it's good, but also 9.2Mb! So I used the csv mentioned by @Ashwini_Chaudhary (https://stackoverflow.com/a/16253118/1937033) with only 9.6Kb: geohack.net/gis/wikipedia-iso-country-codes.csv

Comment: why not `code.split('-')[0]` ?

Answer (score 1):

[List of ISO 639-2 codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-2_codes) at Wikipedia has a table specifying the correspondence. Since it's not a 1-1 mapping, the conversion is not always possible.

You *did* miss something - it's quite possible to do the conversion with the libraries you specified.

- [BabelFish — babelfish 0.5.1 documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/babelfish/):

> Built-in language converters (alpha2, alpha3b, alpha3t, name, scope,
>   type and opensubtitles):
>
> ```
> >>> language = babelfish.Language('por', 'BR')
> >>> language.alpha2
> 'pt'
> <...>
> >>> babelfish.Language.fromalpha3b('fre')
> <Language [fr]>
> ```

- `langcodes` is tailored for different tasks - recognizing and matching languages regardless of standards. So you can extract all the codes that are related to your initial one - to varying extents - but it will not tell you which standards they pertain to.
- `pycountry` is similar to `babelfish` and is covered by [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34302890/648265).

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I did indeed miss something. My comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34302586/convert-iso-639-1-to-iso-639-2#comment56366849_34302890) explains what it was.

Comment: @sampablokuper Well, I did miss _that part of your confusion_ - because I never had it in the first place (the Wikipedia table lists two-letter codes - two-letter codes it is!).

Comment: ivan_pozdeev, right! Depends on which Wikipedia table one consults, though :) Sorry my confusion was confusing ;)