# How do I get the country name from a given ISO-3166-1 alpha-2 code in Python?

Tags: python, country-codes, iso-3166

I want the user to input a ISO-3166-1 alpha-2 code.

```
country_code = input("Please enter a country's two-letter code (e.g. FR, US) :")
```

I then want to translate the code into the country's name:

```
FR -> France
US -> United States of America
```

https://laendercode.net/en/2-letter-list.html

How can I do this ?

Comment: Using a dict to translate an abbreviation to the full word -- this is *much* easier.
However, you still haven't done the expected research.  This is a common technique, which you should look up on this site, rather than posting a question.

Comment: I didn't find good tagg for search, i find all document about Google Translator but that's not really what i need, do you have any documentation ? I have update my topic i hope he is now better ?

Comment: Here's the opposite question: [How to convert country names to ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 values, using python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16253060/4518341)

Comment: Thanks a lots that's exactly what i need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the module `pycountry`, in the command line run `pip install pycountry`, and then in your code:

```py
import pycountry
country_code = input("Please choose a country tag (like fr, us...): ")
country = pycountry.countries.get(alpha_2=country_code)
country_name = country.name
```

For more info see [this](https://pypi.org/project/pycountry/)

Comment: pycountry [doesn't seem to be maintained](https://github.com/flyingcircusio/pycountry/issues/158).

Comment: Confirming that this library is being actively maintained.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `country_converter`, install with `pip install country_converter`.
This is around 50kb compared to `pycountry` being around 10mb.

Conversion is easy with something like:

```
import country_converter as coco
input_country = input(" Please choose a contry tagg (like fr, us...) :")
converted_country = coco.convert(names=input_country, to="name")
print(converted_country)
```

- `names` can be singular or a list which can be mixed input

  - `names="fr"`
  - `names=["fr", "USA", "826", 276, "China"]`

There are *a lot* of classification schemes listed in the documentation that can be taken as inputs or converted to .

Answer (score 0):

This is referred to as "internationalization", and the Python module for doing this is [gettext](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gettext.html#internationalizing-your-programs-and-modules). For example:

> In order to prepare your code for I18N, you need to look at all the strings in your files. Any string that needs to be translated should be marked by wrapping it in _('...') — that is, a call to the function _(). For example:

```
filename = 'mylog.txt'
message = _('writing a log message')
with open(filename, 'w') as fp:
    fp.write(message)
```

This is a complex subject and that page will give you a lot of information to start with.

Comment: Sry i have edit my question, i just wan't to replace variable into the real country